# Como validar se arquivos de um diretório são ou estão ocultos?

Tags: c#

Bom dia, Pessoal.

Existe um programa que imprime arquivos do tipo PDF que estão em um diretório pré-definido.

O problema estava acontecendo porque existiam dois arquivos ocultos pasta e o programa estava tentando imprimir e estourava o erro conforme o print abaixo:

[image: Erro causado por existir arquivo oculto na pasta]

Como eu faço para verificar se arquivo encontrado na pasta é oculto ?

Comment: Tenta ver este post, acho que é o que precisas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39561848/how-to-check-whether-a-file-is-hidden?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @JoanaBrandão, obrigado pela dica, vou olhar esse post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido o problema com o código abaixo. Dependendo não precisaria ter criado um método, porém, no meu caso ficou melhor dessa forma.

```
private Boolean IsFileHidden(string arquivo)
{
    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(arquivo);
    if (fileInfo.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```